# Why is created_at converted to Zulu format in Interia.js?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I am using Laravel 8 together with Interia.js.

I have a simple route like this:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $user = User::first();
    return Inertia::render('Test', compact('user'));
});
```

If I dump the user in controller I see that the attribute `created_at` is in format "YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s". However, at the front end the timestamp is presented in Zulu format. Why? And how can I prevent this conversion?

Currently I have to reformat like this at the front-end:

```
{{ new Date(user.create_at).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')}}
```

[image]

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting describes how you can override this

Comment: @apokryfos thank you. I knew about Carbon conversion, but didn't know it also handles json conversion. It states in the docs that its recommended not to change the json time format  `You are strongly encouraged to always use this serialization format` - do you know why?

Comment: Firstly this is an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date so it's generally good to follow standards for interoperability. I also like this format because it's unambigious because it includes the timezone. `YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s` is not clear with respect to timezone and since you are sending it to the user's browser when the browser tries to parse it then it might assume the wrong timezone